# Determine why bundler is taking so long to load files?

Tags: rspec, bundler

Bundler is taking a very long time to load files, and I'm trying to pinpoint why:

```
$ bundle exec rspec

<bunch of output>

Finished in 1.08 seconds (files took 2 minutes 2.6 seconds to load)
```

I've tried a couple things without success:

1. I commented out everything in the `spec_helper.rb`, thinking it might be doing expensive setup.  This didn't change the file load time, however.
2. I tried executing `bundle exec rspec -v` to see if the problem was bundler itself (unrelated to our code).  However, this command returns in a few seconds.

Note: This is a ruby command line application, not a Rails app.

### Questions

1. What might be causing these long load times?
2. Any suggestions for debugging techniques that would pinpoint the source of the problem?

Comment: The "files took 2 minutes 2.6 seconds to load" part is not emitted from bundler but from rspec.  The setup of bundler is finished before rspec even starts its measuring. Thus, you (likely) don't need to improve your bundler setup but the organisation of your rspec tests. If you are using Rails, it might just be the initial Rails startup in which case [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) might help.